# Javascript: execCommand("removeformat") doesn't strip h2 tag

Tags: javascript

I'm tweaking a wysiwyg editor, and I'm trying to create an icon which will strip selected text of `h2`.

In a previous version, the following command worked perfectly:

```
oRTE.document.execCommand("removeformat", false, "");
```

But in the current version, although that command successfully removes from selected text such tags as bold, underline, italics, it leaves the `h2` tag intact.

(Interestingly enough, `execCommand("formatblock"...)` successfully creates the `h2` tag.)

I'm thinking that I'm going to have to abandon `execCommand` and find another way, but I'm also thinking that it will be a lot more than just 1 line of code! Would be grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

You can change your format to div, it's not the best solution but it works and it's short:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div')
```

There is also this other solution to get the closest parent from selected text then you can unwrap it, note that this can be some tag like <b>:

```
var container = null;
if (document.selection) //for IE
    container = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
else {
    var select = window.getSelection();
    if (select.rangeCount > 0)
        container = select.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
}
$(container).contents().unwrap(); //for jQuery1.4+
```

Answer (score 5):

This is in accordance with the proposed [W3C Editing APIs](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-removeformat-command). It has a list of formatting elements, and the `H#` elements are not listed. These are considered structural, not simply formatting. It doesn't make any more sense to remove these tags than it would to remove `UL` or `P`.

Comment: I guess I should have made my question more explicit: so what do I do now?

Comment: If you need to remove specific elements, use explicit DOM manipulation  functions to search for them and remove them. jQuery can help reduce the number of lines of code.

Comment: I posted here to get more detailed answers than that. And keeping in mind that I need to remove the h2 tag only from the currently highlighted text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the **Range** object.
you can find it from  Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd Edition.
chapter 12(12.4) and chapter 14(14.5) ...

an example from that book:

```
var selection = frames["richedit"].getSelection();

var selectedText = selection.toString();

var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

var span = frames["richedit"].document.createElement("span");
span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
range.surroundContents(span);
```